# LaunchEvents key unrecognized in launchd plist (detecting USB device)

Tags: macos, plist, launchd

I want to launch a specific app when a USB device is plugged in to a Mac OS X system.  I've followed the recipe given in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12259762/558639).  But it appears the `LaunchEvents` key is not recognized: When I reboot my system, I see the following message on the console:

```
com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[173]  (com.example.program) Unknown key for dictionary: LaunchEvents
```

I am running OS X 10.6.8, and it's entirely possible that xpc_events aren't supported in this version of OS X.  If this is the case, what are my alternatives?

(As a second, lesser question: is there a way to force a re-read of my .plist file without rebooting the system?  It would speed up debugging time!)

The entire contents of `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.example.plist` follows.  (Note that for debugging, I'm simply trying to launch the Terminal.app using /usr/bin/open.  I'll swap in my real program once I get this much working.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd >
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.program</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/bin/open</string>
      <string>/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app</string>
    </array>
    <key>LaunchEvents</key>
    <dict>
      <key>com.apple.iokit.matching</key>
      <dict>
        <key>com.apple.device-attach</key>
        <dict>
          <key>idProduct</key>
          <integer>8963</integer>
          <key>idVendor</key>
          <integer>1659</integer>
          <key>IOProviderClass</key>
          <string>IOUSBDevice</string>
          <key>IOMatchStream</key>
          <true/>
        </dict>
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2):

To reload first unload and then load:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.example.plist
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.example.plist
```